# Flutter web application memory is increased after refresh page

Tags: flutter, memory-leaks, flutter-web

We have created a flutter web application. When we run the web application in release mode it takes 200 MB Memory at start-up. We have checked it with Chrome task manager tool.

Issue is when we refresh the web application a few times(3-4), it increases memory (i.e., 300 MB) but after few seconds it is not coming down to the actual 200MB.

We have also checked Flutter dev-tools, but for web application it is not showing memory and performance section.

There could be two possibilities:

1. Memory leak issue - But how to see that without dev-tools support
2. Flutter's own garbage collection issue?

If anybody has any idea about it, please share.

Comment: I'm currently trying to find out some of this stuff myself. Just found out the Memory and Performance tabs, amongst others, are not available for Flutter web, so you should run your app in the Emulator/Simulator. I read somewhere here on StackOverflow that there is a known issue with Flutters garbage collection in Flutter web, but I'm awaiting response as to where this information comes from and if it's legit. If you find anything useful, please let me know, I'll make sure to keep you updated about my findings here as well.

Comment: did you happen to figure this out? i have the same issue

Comment: Did you find any way to handle it?